# Javamail API - MessageCountListener is not getting Called

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to read Unread mail from my gmail Inbox using Javamail API.
Here is my code ...

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    String attachFiles = "";
    try
    {
        final Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        final Store store = session.getStore();
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "*********", "*********");
        final Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        final MailCountEventListener listener = new MailCountEventListener();
        inbox.addMessageCountListener(listener);


        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        final Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
        final Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
        for (final Address address : in)
        {
            System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
        }
        final Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
        final BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
        if (msg.getContentType().contains("multipart"))
        {
            final int numberOfParts = mp.getCount();
            for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++)
            {
                final MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) mp.getBodyPart(partCount);
                if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition()))
                {
                    // this part is attachment
                    final String fileName = part.getFileName();
                    attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                    part.saveFile("E:/" + File.separator + fileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("MultiPart Message Content :" + part.getContent().toString());
                }
            }

            if (attachFiles.length() > 1)
            {
                attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
            }

            System.out.println("Attachments: " + attachFiles);
        }
        System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
        System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
        System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());
    }
    catch (final Exception mex)
    {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My code is working fine. It is reading mail body with attached templates. Now I want to call `MessageCountListener` so that if any new Mail will come into my Inbox, Listener should be called automatically and read new mail body.

But Here the problem is My listener is not calling.

```
public class MailCountEventListener implements MessageCountListener
{


/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see javax.mail.event.MessageCountListener#messagesAdded(javax.mail.event.MessageCountEvent)
 */
@Override
public void messagesAdded(final MessageCountEvent messagecountevent)
{

    String attachFiles = "";

    System.out.println("message listner invoked.");
    final Message[] msgs = messagecountevent.getMessages();

    System.out.println("Got " + msgs.length + " new messages");
    try
    {
        final Message msg = msgs[0];
        final Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
        for (final Address address : in)
        {
            System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
        }
        final Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
        final BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
        if (msg.getContentType().contains("multipart"))
        {
            final int numberOfParts = mp.getCount();
            for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++)
            {
                final MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) mp.getBodyPart(partCount);
                if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition()))
                {
                    // this part is attachment
                    final String fileName = part.getFileName();
                    attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                    part.saveFile("E:/" + File.separator + fileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("MultiPart Message Content :" + part.getContent().toString());
                }
            }

            if (attachFiles.length() > 1)
            {
                attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
            }

            System.out.println("Attachments: " + attachFiles);
        }
        System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
        System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
        System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());

    }
    catch (final Exception mex)
    {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see javax.mail.event.MessageCountListener#messagesRemoved(javax.mail.event.MessageCountEvent)
 */
@Override
public void messagesRemoved(final MessageCountEvent messagecountevent)
{
    // YTODO Auto-generated method stub

}

  }
```

adding Listener ..

```
final MailCountEventListener listener = new MailCountEventListener();
inbox.addMessageCountListener(listener);
```

I am not able to figure out where I am doing wrong. My event is not calling. Please help

Answer (score 2):

The server only notifies the client of new messages as part of executing a command.  You either need to execute a command periodically, e.g., by calling getMessageCount, or you need to use the [IMAP IDLE support](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#idle%28%29) to wait for notifications.  See also the [IdleManager](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IdleManager.html) that's new in [JavaMail 1.5.2](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added `IdleManager` to my eventListener. but still It is not notifying me for new Message.

Comment: Another doubt is I am trying to get List of recent Message `messages = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.RECENT), true));
System.out.println("messages >>>>>>>" + messages.length);` but Why I am always getting 0 length.

Comment: Maybe we could keep this post to one problem at a time?  :-)  If your event listener is still not getting called, we're going to need more details, such as the code you're using and the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) with your server.  It's important to determine whether your server is even sending the notifications to begin with.

Comment: @BillShannon i have the same issue as the OP - I'm not seeing anything when I send the email. After calling `store.idle()`, the debug trace on the IMAP session just says `+ IDLE accepted, awaiting DONE command.` and that's all. What should I look for next to figure out why there's no event?

Comment: It would be better if you started a new question with details of what you're doing and what's happening.  Include the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  Or send the details to me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.

Comment: OK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919541/javamail-event-listener-not-getting-any-events